# How do I make a webpage respond to different scale widths?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, scale

I'm starting to learn how to make a 'Responsive web page' and have so far just used the width of the window the web page is displayed in to change the layout. I'm wondering if there's a way to detect the scale of the monitor it's displayed in (if it's 4:3, standard 16:9, 21:9, etc) to change the layout since 1440p (2560x1440) and Ultrawide 1080p (2560x1080) shares the same pixel width.

Comment: CSS pixels != Device actual pixels!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting width and height in one media query, separated with the word "and":

```
   @media (min-height: 500px) and (min-width: 580px) {
        /* CSS stuff */
    }
```

With such media query you can target different proportions of the screen - even while having same widths.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. To do it in CSS, combine two media queries with the word `and`:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1336px) and (min-height: 768px) {
  /* Your code */
}
```

To do it in javascript, just divide `screen.width` by `screen.height`to get the aspect ratio:

```
var aspectratio = screen.width / screen.height
```